# Default zoom Mapbox when used in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, mapbox

Does anyone know how to set a default point when zooming out using the MapBox app in Power BI? Currently, when I deselect the location in a slicer connected to the map, it will zoom out to the very middle of the world map. I would like set a custom marker to zoom out to if possible.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no out of the box feature within the Mapbox visual for Power BI that prevents you from zooming past a certain point, as the default zoom level is set to include all of your data. For instance, if I create a report with a choropleth map of US states, when using the slicer, the map will zoom into the state I select. When I deselect the state, the map will zoom back out to show all of the states.

[image]

[image]

If you have data spanning multiple regions (or if the data is only visible at higher zoom levels), when you deselect the location in the slicer, the map will zoom out to incorporate all data. While the Mapbox visual is currently available as is, please stay tuned for updates.

Answer (score 0):

MapBox

**Viz Settings:**

- Zoom 0-10 ( preferably 9 )
- Lat ( central latitude )
- Lot ( central longitude )

I tried it and it worked for me... The map comes with the zoom setting I want initially

[image: My solution]